# How do I query a database for only one field of a resultset? (JAVA ODBC)

Tags: java, jdbc

I have an assignment I am working on (and trying to debug). I have a JComboBox which I need to fill with only ISBN numbers.  The Database returns ISBNs, BookTitle, QuantityOnHand, and Price.  I am to make a method (loadCombo) which is to load the comboBox with (as I said) only the ISBN numbers. I have this little snippet written:

```
    public static void loadCombo(JComboBox box)
{
   String query = "SELECT * FROM Books";

   try
   {
       result = statement.executeQuery(query);
       result.getString(1);            
       addISBN(result,box);
   }
   catch(SQLException sqlex)  {sqlex.printStackTrace();}
    public static void addISBN(ResultSet result,JComboBox box)
{
    try
    {
         while(result.next()) {box.addItem(result);}
    }
    catch(SQLException e)   {e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

However, this throws a load of errors.  What am I doing wrong here? I thought that I was making a resultSet (result), then getting the first field (result.getString(1)), and then throwing the resultset  and combobox to my addISBN method which will add the resultset to my comboBox?

So I did what the first answer said (thank you for the advice, I guess I should read my assignments a little more carefully!).  However, I now crash on the addISBN method. My ISBN textbox has 14 lines, all say

'sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcReseltSet@13f9460'

Comment: For the error I guess it cause by {box.addItem(result);} use {box.addItem(result.getString(1));} and I think you don't need the result.getString(1); before addISBN(result,box);. See duffymo answer

Comment: Thanks @Ace, appreciate the tip!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your UI and combo box should not come within one hundred yards of persistence code.  It's called layering or separation of concerns.  Tell your professor that it's considered a best practice in the real world.

This code is heinous.  I'd write it more like this.  Notice how I close those resources in the scope of the method in which they were created.  That's important.  No JDBC classes should leak out of the persistence package.  Load the results into a data structure (in this case, a List of Strings for ISBNs).

Java's an object-oriented language.  Where's the Book model class?

```
package persistence;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * BookDao
 * @author Michael
 * @since 4/6/11
 */
public class BookDao
{
    public static final String SELECT_ALL_BOOKS = "SELECT * FROM Books";

    private Connection connection;

    public BookDao(Connection connection)
    {
        this.connection = connection;
    }

    public List<String> find() throws SQLException
    {
        List<String> isbn= new ArrayList<String>();

        Statement statement = null;
        ResultSet result = null;

        try
        {
            statement = this.connection.createStatement();
            result = statement.executeQuery(SELECT_ALL_BOOKS);
            while (result.next())
            {
                isbn.add(result.getString(1));
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            close(result);
            close(statement);
        }

        return isbn;
    }

    private static void close(ResultSet result)
    {
        try
        {
            if (result != null)
            {
                result.close();
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void close(Statement statement)
    {
        try
        {
            if (statement != null)
            {
                statement.close();
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 nice points.. this same with my coding structure.. though I have an AbstractDAO because of many different queries. @unit this will be a great if you follow this techniques.

Comment: Unfortunately, if I follow this, I will be told that I have not been taught half of it, and will lose marks for copying something off of the internet.  I do appreciate the points, however, it makes me a little sad to see that I am being taught 'heinous' coding techniques.

Comment: But you have been taught, just not by your professor.  Things like "close your resources" and "layers".  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Might want to construct a proper SQL statement. Instead of SELECT * FROM Books, use SELECT [column name in db] FROM Books

edit: What unit wrote in his comment.

Comment: agree with the approach but that still doesn't solve poster's problem that is causing by referencing to result instead of to the string returned by result.setString(1)

Comment: Okay, that's pretty fair.  I rechecked my assignment, because I thought it stipulated that you had to use SELECT *.   I was wrong...... So I changed that to SELECT ISBN FROM Books, and that worked, but now it crashes when it tries to add the resultSet.

Answer (score 1):

REmove the result.getString(1); line.  With a ResultSet, you need to do a next() before you can access the resultset elements, as there is no current row prior to a next();

Also, for the future, you are much more likely to get good responses if you post the exception details.

Answer (score 0):

```
String myStr = result.getString(1);
```

Then use `myStr` instead of `result`. use `result`  only to navigate to the next row.

Reference - [ResultSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html)

Comment: My assignment stipulates that I have to pass a resultSet to my addISBN method.

Comment: In that case, change box.addItem(result); to box.addItem(result.getString(1)); result is the resultset object, NOT the individual record value. You cannot get the individual  record value unless you call getString (or similar. See ResulSet api) on the resultset